# Disable anti-alias QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

How to disable anti-alias in QGIS using PyQGIS? I need to create output rasters (tiff / png) which has not used antialised using QGIS Composer / Atlas. Do you have some PyQGIS commands for novice (not programmer) which command need to use?

Indeed unclicking "Enable antialising" will create raster without antialising except texts and symbols, which will appear still antialised. I need to create whole raster without antialising. Also texts and symbols need to force to use without antialising.

Answer (score 0):

When you export the map you can untick "Enable antialiasing".

[image]

Comment: Indeed unclicking "Enable antialising" will create raster without antialising except text and symbol will appear still antialised. I need to create whole raster without antialising